# axios will not send request body data to my express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am using axios to do AJAX calls to my Express web server. Whenever I make a post request and pass in a piece of data, the data is for some reason never sent to the server. Whenever I check the request.body, no data is ever there even though I clearly added it.

```
<script>

    axios.post("/api/users", {
        firstname: 'fred'
    })
        .then(function(res){
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
</script>
```

The above is the AJAX Post request I am making with axios. As you can see, I passed in a piece of data: "firstname" to be sent to "/api/users".

```
app.post("/api/users", function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
res.send({newData: req.body.firstname});
});
```

This is my very simple post route that it is sending to. I am simply passing the data that I sent back to the client. Whenever this runs, "firstname" is never found. When I check the console.log, the req.body is empty, and the .then console.log on the client side only shows some random "_proto_" object, but not what I sent. I've done exactly as the documentation says, why isn't "firstname" going through??

EDIT: I just tried with fetch, it still didn't work. It seems like any AJAX request is just not working right, the data doesn't go through.

Comment: Are you using [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)?

Comment: Okay so as it turns out, I had "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))" but I didn't set "app.use(bodyParser.json())", so thank you for the body-parser suggestions!